# why oracle isqlplus localhost does not open in my browser?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

**Oracle Database Connection:**
I am using oracle database and when I open oracle SQL plus in start folder it opens my Netbeans and connect into a database everything  looks good.

**Issue:**
When i try to access `http://localhost:5560/isqlplus/` it shows the error[image] 
I have verified all the services of oracle except isqlplushome that is not running its show that is disabled 
I try the following in command prompt and which gives following output.

> c:\Users\pc>isqlplus start

```
CNTService::Install,Failed call to open SCM,Error:5,Access is denied
can anybody help me
```

Comment: check if the service is enabled.

Comment: i already did that  but doesn't work thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows, try to look for oracle services and restart them.
If it still remains try to reconfigure a new listener.ora as mentioned in the official documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/network.920/a96581/listener.htm

Answer (score 4):

iSQLPlus was introduced with Oracle 8i. In version 9i, it ran in web browser (so you didn't have to install any client software). It was desupported in 11g.

Which means: unless your database version is not between 8i and 10g, you can't use iSQLPlus.

What to do? Use SQL Developer.

Comment: and now you can use SQL Developer Web - which will give you an interface to run your queries/scripts - in your browser https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/12/sql-developer-web-is-now-available/

Comment: No i was work with it before and it still work with oracle 10g